# executing sequence of static methods in java

Tags: java, static-methods

I have a dummy program in java given below-

```
public class DummyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hungry(null);
    }

     public static void hungry(Object o){
        System.out.println("object");
    }

    public static void hungry(String s){
        System.out.println("string");
    }
}
```

this program returns prints `string`. please tell me the concept that why it prints `string` and not `object`.

Comment: This is nothing to do with `static`, the same principle applies to any method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how method overloading works. When the parameter of one candidate is more specific than the parameter of the other (as `String` is more specific than `Object`), the method with the more specific parameter is chosen.

Note that if you add a 3rd `hungry` method with a parameter of reference type unrelated to `String` (for example `Integer`), the code won't pass compilation since the compiler won't have a preference between `hungry(String)` and `hungry(Integer)`.